# Django Model Manager for Default Options

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model which has a foreign key that is optional. I set it up this way so that table would contain default options of different `service_types` but one could override this option by specifying a `controller` foreign key.

Now in my views I have a bunch of code that looks like this:

```
try:
    modeService = RegressionServices.objects.get(controller=controller, service_type=SERVICE_TYPE_CONTROLLER_MODE)
except RegressionServices.DoesNotExist:
    modeService = RegressionServices.objects.get(service_type=SERVICE_TYPE_CONTROLLER_MODE)
```

I would like to reduce this down to one call and I think that a Django model `Manager` should be the way to do so. Essentially it would check for the controller in `**kwargs` and if present it would basically do the code above. I am looking in the docs and only finding that the `get_query_set` method is usually being overridden. Is it okay to override the `get()` method? Will I even have access to the `RegressionServices` model in a model Manager `get()` method?

Can anyone think of a way to do this other than a model manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a logical OR, using [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: If ``RegressionServices`` has two entries with the same service type (which it will), one with a controller FK and one without, a ``MultipleObjectsReturned`` exception is thrown, so that doesn't work.

Comment: If there's potential for multiple objects being returned, either don't use `get` or catch the exception and respond accordingly. In your case, you should probably be using `filter` with subscript syntax to impose a limit (e.g. `RegressionServices.objects.filter(...)[0]`) and catching `IndexError` to ensure at least one item was returned.